# docker commands not found

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, command

I installed docker in Mac and it is installed successfully.
Also it is running.
And tried to execute the below command in terminal

```
docker -v
```

See the below error:

```
-bash: docker: command not found
```

How do I solve this issue.
In windows those commands are working fine.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009138/docker-command-not-found-when-running-on-mac

Comment: why are you not accepting the answer given? Please accept it if it worked for you or clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you successfully installed docker using the official package, the command should be available under `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

That directory might not yet be in your `$PATH`, so you could try adding `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile`.

Comment: bash is not the official termianl for mac anymore. What would the zsh version be?

Comment: that does not add it permentantly to my path...

Comment: I added more details to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71876799/1601580 thanks dorian! :D